# How to get LibGdx's orthographic camera view in a Blender imported 3D world?

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx, blender

Specifically I created a Blender 3D world.
I want to use LibGdx's camera view to use the 3D world as a Background with 3D Objects on it.
I am creating an android game where my 3D player runs Forward in Y Direction.
How do I go about changing the ground into the 2D Background and have the 3D Objects remain the same to Simulate 3D feel.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: More specifically, what do you mean by "changing the ground into the 2D Background and have the 3D Objects remain the same to Simulate 3D feel". You want to render you world into an image and use that? You might want to look into 2.5D and Box2d Lights but it's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Take away the 3D Objects for a second, I want the 3D World to be viewed in an orthographic view in which I can move around in from that view. Then how to put the 3D Objects onto the 3D world (which would look 2D now) but Keep the 3D Objects 3D.